# HTML CSS Overflow not working

Tags: css, overflow

![enter image description here][1]I want to make a horizontal line after my text.

Instead of hiding the content that goes out of the div (#line), it doesn't display it at all.
The #line div has to be bigger than the `#textline` div because I don't know the size of the text div.

Edit: Here is the Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wakary/8tTzz/2/

Put #line {width: 100;} to see what I want to accomplish.

Edit: (what I want to acheve, the title changes):

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can use "]]" as an ID.

Comment: You're not really using three! DIVs to draw a single line? The image also looks nothing like what you have in your fiddle – even when stripping the `overflow: hidden;`…

Comment: @BillyMoat That's `ll`. Install a new font on your PC ;-)

Comment: It works if I make the line smaller http://jsfiddle.net/wakary/8tTzz/2/  But I want it to be widder than the #linetext div

Comment: @feeela How would you do it then? (I don't mind doing something simpler, I just couldn't think of anything else)

Comment: @user1675769 The question is, want you want to achieve. Is there another parent element for the text, how many do you got per page, …

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/UEeKN/

Comment: @feeela Updated info with a new pic.

Comment: @feeela In your Fiddle the lines width is static, I want it to change according to the length of the text.

Comment: It isn't showing the line because it's being moved below your text and hidden.

Comment: @DerekAdair I know, that's what I want, the line to stay, not move under.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have made some small changes to your code

```
#textline{
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 36px;
margin-left: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#text{
position: absolute;
color: green;
height: 36px;
background:white;
padding-right:10px;
}
#line{   
position: absolute;
height: 10px;
width: 80%;  
border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

And the HTML like this

```
<div id="textline">
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

So in this case you will have one div over the other, the line will cover all it´s container, and the text will hide some part of this line.

Comment: I can't use this method because I have a background image not just white background.

Comment: also, the line does not change size based on the length of the text in the header.

Comment: So try to use the same image in the background of the text.

Comment: That's my last resort solution.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the width of the container element works.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tTzz/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="textline">
    <div id="text">Text</div>
    <div id="line">
        <div id="upspace"></div>
        <div id="ll"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#textline
{
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
#text
{
    float: left;
    color: green;
    height: 36px;
}
#line
{
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    width: 400px;    
}
#upspace
{
    height: 10px;
}
#ll
{
    height: 1px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I want the text and line to be in a fixed width container. The text to change length and the line to change length according to the text.